# Processing AWS IoT messages with Lambda functions

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-iot

I'm trying to develop a lambda function in C# to process and transform the data which I receive from AWS IoT core in the same way I did with the data from DynamoDB, S3 or SQS for example.

What I would like to know is if I have to subscribe to the topic obligatorily, transform each message and finally send it to s3, DyanmoDB or whatever or I can access directly to this data without subscribe.

The code:

```js
 var CaCert = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(@"C:\...\rootCA.pem");
                var clientCert = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\...\amazon.pfx");
                string ClientID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();


                var IotClient = new MqttClient(IotEndPoint, BrokerPort, true, CaCert, clientCert, MqttSslProtocols.TLSv1_2);
                IotClient.MqttMsgPublishReceived += Client_MqttMsgPublishReceived;

                IotClient.Connect(ClientID);
                Console.WriteLine("Connected to IoT Core. Waiting for the frames...");
                IotClient.Subscribe(new string[] { topic }, new byte[] { MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_AT_LEAST_ONCE });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to subscribe to the topic(s) to access the data. However, you can simply write your topic subscription SQL expression to use a wildcard like [this example from the official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-sql-from.html) to avoid having to subscribe to each individual topic:

> You can use the # wildcard character to match any subpath in a topic
>   filter:
>
> Example:
>
> Incoming payload published on topic 'a/b': {temperature: 50}.
>
> Incoming payload published on topic 'a/c': {temperature: 60}.
>
> Incoming payload published on topic 'a/e/f': {temperature: 70}.
>
> Incoming payload published on topic 'b/x': {temperature: 80}.
>
> SQL: "SELECT temperature AS t FROM 'a/#'".
>
> The rule is subscribed to any topic beginning with 'a', so it is
>   executed three times, sending outgoing payloads of {t: 50} (for a/b),
>   {t: 60} (for a/c), and {t: 70} (for a/e/f) to its actions. It is not
>   subscribed to 'b/x', so the rule will not be triggered for the
>   {temperature: 80} message.

Comment: I just did for work locally: I run the program in a local computer and then it subscribe to a topic to received the data. But now, to use it in a lambda function, how can I access to the certificates: .pem and .pfx?

Comment: Why do you need to access the certificates in the Lambda function? In the IoT management console you should be configuring it to send messages to your Lambda function. That's all you need to do. Then the Lambda function will be called with the message as a parameter.

Comment: You're right. In the lambda function, which would be the event to use the IoT data (in c#)? I did with DynamoDB, for example, with the DynamoDBEvent as the FunctionHandler parameter, but I don't see the event to use with IoT. I tried with string, but I get this error: _Error converting the Lambda event JSON payload to a string. JSON strings must be quoted, for example "Hello World" in order to be converted to a string: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value_

Comment: Using (object input) as FunctionHandler parameter the problem is fixed, but i'm not sure if this is the best way

Comment: I usually start with Object and then have the code print the object's type to see what event type Lambda will be passing in.